# rails autocomplete searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, autocomplete

I'm trying to get an autocomplete working with typeahead.js

This is what i have at the moment.

This is in my controller.

```
  def autocomplete
    render json: Event.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10).map(&:eventname)
  end
```

This is in my routes

```
resources :events do
      collection do
        get :autocomplete
      end
    end
```

If i use the rails console and do this

```
Event.search("searchquery", autocomplete: true).map(&:eventname)
```

i do get the expected response,

However

If i search using the normal searchbox on my site i get this error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Event with 'id'=autocomplete):
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:50:in `show'
```

On line 50 in the show (which is used elsewhere) is this

```
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
```

This is whats in my view

```
    <div class="col-md-12" align="center" style="padding-top: 1%">
      <%= javascript_include_tag "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.9.3/ typeahead.min.js" %>
    <h1><%= image_tag("Logo.png", :class => "logo", :style => "background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); border-radius: 50px") %></h1>
    <%= form_tag search_events_path, class: "form-inline form-wrapper", method: :get do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "What are you looking for?", class: "search-module-input-text", id: "search", autocomplete: "off" %>
          <%= submit_tag "Search", id: "submit" %>
      </div>
```

I was trying to follow this tutorial

https://shellycloud.com/blog/2013/10/adding-search-and-autocomplete-to-a-rails-app-with-elasticsearch

I only got as far as adding the searchcode as you see above

Any help would be great!!!

Sam

**edit**

Heres the show part of the controller and the search part

```
  def search
    @events = Event.search params[:search], suggest: true, partial: true, misspellings: {distance: 4}
    if @events.results.any?
      render 'events/results'
    else
      render 'events/noresults'
    end
  end

  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @stubby = stub_auth_token
  end
```

rails console

```
curl http://localhost:9200/events_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"multi_match":{"fields":["eventname.autocomplete"],"query":"response","analyzer":"searchkick_autocomplete_search"}},"size":1000,"from":0,"fields":[]}'
  Event Load (3.5ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" IN (23419, 23420, 16330, 16329, 13660)
 => ["reponse1", "reponse2", "reponse3", "reponse4", "reponse5"]
```

Comment: show the `show` method of `events_controller`

Comment: Now add the Rails console log what you see when you hit this request.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I'll add it but it'll have to be edited for reasons

Comment: Did you get the routing correct? It shouldn't be hitting #show at all right? Check rake routes?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Added the edit, The rake routes do show this      `autocomplete_events GET    /events/autocomplete(.:format)       events#autocomplete`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
<%= form_tag autocomplete_events_path, ... %>
```

Comment: Can you check your before_filters to see if the find_event or something of sorts is not applied to #autocomplete?

Comment: Well if i remove the search_events tag it just stops searching completely!